# Send User Entered Form data from one component to another in react-redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I need to view the user entered input data for the user before saving them to db.

In this component i am validating the input data `Step1.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Row, Col, Label } from "reactstrap";
import { Control, LocalForm, Errors } from "react-redux-form";

const required = val => val && val.length;
const maxLength = len => val => !val || val.length <= len;
const minLength = len => val => val && val.length >= len;
export default class Step1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    // explicit class assigning based on validation

    return (
      <div className="step step3">
        <div className="row">
          <LocalForm>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label className="col-md-12 control-label">
                <h1>Step 1: Enter User Details</h1>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-12 content form-block-holder">
              <Label htmlFor="firstname" className="control-label col-md-4">
                First Name
              </Label>
              <Col md={8}>
                <Control.text
                  model=".firstname"
                  id="firstname"
                  name="firstname"
                  placeholder="First Name"
                  className="form-control"
                  validators={{
                    required,
                    minLength: minLength(3),
                    maxLength: maxLength(15)
                  }}
                />
                <Errors
                  className="text-danger"
                  model=".firstname"
                  show="touched"
                  messages={{
                    required: "Required",
                    minLength: "Must be greater than 2 characters",
                    maxLength: "Must be 15 characters or less"
                  }}
                />
              </Col>
            </div>
          </LocalForm>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After validation i need to send the input to another component `Step2.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Data from './Step3'
export default class Step2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  jumpToStep(toStep) {
    // We can explicitly move to a step (we -1 as its a zero based index)
    this.props.jumpToStep(toStep-1); // The StepZilla library injects this jumpToStep utility into each component
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="step step5 review">
        <div className="row">
          <form id="Form" className="form-horizontal">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label className="col-md-12 control-label">
                <h1>Step 4: Review your Details and 'Save'</h1>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <div className="col-md-12 control-label">
                <div className="col-md-12 txt">
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    FirstName
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    {this.props.FirstName} // How can i render my FIRSTNAME and display it here.
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Once after this i will send data to my DB.

Question:

How can i pass the validated data from `Step1` to `Step2` component ? Do i need to store the data before sending them to another component ?

How can i do it ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can do it following the Wizard form concept.

So if you have 3 Steps, then your 3 forms should be configured in the same way as following:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'wizard', // <------ same form name for the 3 forms
  destroyOnUnmount: false, // <------ preserve form data
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
  validate
})(WizardFormFirstPage)
```

Doing it in that way, what you fill in Step1, Step2, Step3 will be kept in only one place in your Store. It will be located in: `state.form.wizard`.

So when you submit Step1 successfully (validation will be triggered for each one Step), on the next Step (Step2) you will have access to the already submitted Step1 data via `state.form.wizzard`. The same logic is valid for all others Steps.

[Here's very well documented how to do a Wizard form](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/wizard/) (by the redux-form library).

---

If the Wizard isn't your case, you can access easily access a form values via [formValueSelector](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/) as follows:

```
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form' // ES6

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const selector = formValueSelector('myFormName')
  const firstName = selector(state, 'firstname')

  return { firstName }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jordan , You Mean i need to incorporate my `Step1` and `Step2` using `Wizard form` so that i can able to send values from one to other right ?

Comment: Your example looks like a Wizard form. You have 4 steps. On each step you're adding a new user data to the global form. Finally when everything is validated - you send all the data to the back-end API. However - if this isn't your case - you can easily get the form data via https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/

Comment: `Your example looks like a Wizard form. You have 4 steps. On each step you're adding a new user data to the global form. Finally when everything is validated - you send all the data to the back-end API` Yeah this is my case. BTW i am using `stepzilla` for now . I will try it out with `Wizard form ` .

Comment: Okay. If it resolves your case - you can accept the answer. Otherwise - feel free to ask and close the case :)

Comment: Sure @Jordan thanks for helping will accept if it resolves my problem

Comment: Can i add use your snippet in my `Step2` to get `firstname` value ? Because when i tried it is showing some errors.

Comment: Please create a working JSFiddle and I'll support you. Also the best option for you is to understand and implement the Wizard example I mentioned.